# Empty string array to Union

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two queryable objects to union:

```
    var array1 = query1.Select(x => new Model
    {
       MyArray = x.ProjectsArray
    }).AsQueryable();

    var array2 = query2.Select(x => new Model
    {   
       MyArray = new string[]{}
    }).AsQueryable();

    result = array.Union(array2);
```

How can I create `Array` in `array2` object to `Union` working. Syntax `new string[]{}` is not correct because it return me extension: "The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument".

Comment: `Union` filters out duplicates. Do you perhaps want `Concat` which just appends the second sequence to the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument` because as comments stated it removed duplicated, but cannot do that without a comparer. If you want to add 2 arrays together there are multiple ways to accomplish this. The best way would be to do it like so:

```
var array1 = queryCompanies.Select(x => new Model
{
   MyArray = x.ProjectsArray
}).AsQueryable();

var array2 = queryCompanies.Select(x => new Model
{   
   MyArray = new string[]{}
}).AsQueryable();

var result = array1.Concat(array2);
```

Hope this helps solve your problem :)